# Play segmented, archived video with Microsoft Smooth Streaming

Tags: smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I'm new to Smooth Streaming. I am able to use Microsoft Smooth Streaming player to play live video that spans across multiple segments. The manifest seems to have information about all segments.

But for playback from archive, I am able to point the URL in the HTML to the ISM in one of the segments and I can play back that particular segment fine, but I don't know how to play back the entire video with abilities to rewind, forward, etc.

Is it possible to do such across multiple segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For playing back across multiple segments, I ended up adding the archived segments to the player's playlist and used player.GoToPlaylistItem() and player.SeekToPosition() to forward, rewind and play across multiple segments in an archive.